# My Google Apps script doesn't run on certain devices

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have written a code in Google Apps script and used an `onEdit()` function to trigger it. The program successfully runs on my PC and on my Android devices. The problem arises when I share the Google sheet to my friend 'A', when 'A' tries to trigger the `onEdit()` function, nothing happens (the data on the google sheet remain as it is).

But the same sheet when I share it with my friend 'B', the triggering happens and the program runs successfully.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the devices of my friend 'A'?

(The Google sheet is made public and anyone on the internet could edit it, still 'A' couldn't make it work whereas 'B' could).

PS : It is an installable trigger.

Comment: Is this a simple trigger or an installable trigger? If it's public, you might want to add its link so others can try it out.

Comment: Have you checked the executions tab? Can you see any errors there? Please consider providing more details about this (code, etc). What makes you think it's an issue with the devices, and not with the accounts?